# Android Optimization & CPU Usage Issue

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I've just developed an app for Android, it is a small match matching app. The problem is that when i run my app on a nexus 5, the CPU Usage goes up and then i kill that process (close the app entirely, so it doesn't run in the background) it goes down. So that i checked by using android device monitor tool but i cant able to findout, Only one count is increasing continuously (marked as red color) when i seen in that tool and attached here.I don't even know where to start fixing the problem. Could you guys give me an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take Dump which will give you hprof file. you need to convert this file and use in MAT. Refer this article http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

MAT download for eclipse
https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.mat/releases/1.3.0

Check if your heap memory or dalvik memory is growing and search for respective articles.